# Clarification needed for Jade Syntax

Tags: express, pug

I'm working with Huge's new [Styleguide](http://hugeinc.github.io/styleguide/index.html) templates and am starting to wrap my head around Jade syntax. That said, I can't seem to find any documentation related to how the author created image paths. The syntax used is:

```
img.huge-sidebar__logo.clearfix(src='styleguide/assets/images/#{public.styleguide._data.logoImage}')
```

The part I'm not getting is the section of the path that appears to be an include:

```
#{public.styleguide._data.logoImage}
```

Can anyone shed some light on what this is called and what it's doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is an interesting application of Jade's [interpolation](http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/) functionality, which can be used on plaintext strings, such as is the case with `src='...'`.

It looks different (with the dots) because it's using a multidimensional JavaScript Object rather than simply a variable.